# How do I do JSON-LD Schema for GeoShape Circle?

Tags: json, seo, schema.org, json-ld

Does anyone know how to do the schema for GeoShape Circle?  I am trying to set up a coverage area for my service based business (no physical location).

I would like to do 30 miles in every direction of Sacramento, CA

This is the code I am starting with

```
        "areaServed": [
{
    "@type": "AdministrativeArea",
    "geo": {
        "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
        "latitute": "",
        "longitude": ""
        }
},
```

Comment: @unor is the authority here. I defer to his advice.

Answer (score 3):

The [`areaServed`](http://schema.org/areaServed) property can have a [`GeoShape`](http://schema.org/GeoShape) value directly, no need for `AdministrativeArea` + `geo` (which doesn’t seem to be appropriate for your case, anyway).

And because [`GeoCircle`](http://schema.org/GeoCircle) is a subtype of `GeoShape`, you can use this as value, too.

Then you can provide the [`geoMidpoint`](http://schema.org/geoMidpoint) and the [`geoRadius`](http://schema.org/geoRadius) (in meters if without unit).

So it could look like:

```
"areaServed": {
  "@type": "GeoCircle",
  "geoMidpoint": {
    "@type": "GeoCoordinates",
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": ""
  },
  "geoRadius": "48280.3"
}
```

Comment: TY @unor. Where is the documentation for unitOfMeasure for `geoRadius`? Can't find it on my side.

Comment: @JayGray: You mean how to specify a unit? The format would have to follow the definition from [`Distance`](http://schema.org/Distance) (`<Number> <Length unit of measure>`), but I think there’s no Schema.org list of length units. Just use the well-known/standard terms/abbreviations.